# How do I create a configurable product with associated products?

Tags: magento

The following code does create a configurable product, however, when I open the product in the backend, the following message appears:

Select Configurable Attributes
"Only attributes with scope "Global", input type "Dropdown" and Use To Create Configurable Product "Yes" are available."
A single checkbox is displayed ("Colour Group"), which must be selected before continuing.

When I click "Continue", all of the product data is there as expected EXCEPT for the associated products.

```
//Mage Product
$mpr = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$mpr
    ->setTypeId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE)
    ->setTaxClassId(5)
    ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
    ->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
    ->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
    ->setAttributeSetId(4) // You can determine this another way if you need to.
    ->setSku("C12345")
    ->setName("C12345")
    ->setQty(25)
    ->setShortDescription('short description')
    ->setDescription('description')
    ->setPrice(1)
    ->setStockData(array(
        'use_config_manage_stock' => 1,
        'is_in_stock' => 1,
        'is_salable' => 1,
    ));

    $productData = array(
         '7039604' =>
            array('0' => array('attribute_id' => '85', 'label' => 'ROYAL','value_index' => '28563', 'is_percent' => 0, 'pricing_value' => '')
                 ,'1' => array('attribute_id' => '192', 'label' => '14', 'value_index' => '28728', 'is_percent' => 0, 'pricing_value' => '')
            )
    );
    $attributeData = array(
        '0' => array(
            'id' => NULL
            ,'label' => 'Color'
            ,'position' => NULL
            ,'values' => array(
                '0' => array('value_index' => 28563, 'label' => 'ROYAL', 'is_percent' => 0, 'pricing_value' => '0', 'attribute_id' => '85')
            )
            ,'attribute_id' => 85
            ,'attribute_code' => 'color'
            ,'frontend_label' => 'Color'
            ,'html_id' => 'config_super_product__attribute_0')
        ,'1' => array(
            'id' => NULL
            ,'label' => 'Rivers Size'
            ,'position' => NULL
            ,'values' => array(
                '0' => array('value_index' => 28728, 'label' => '14', 'is_percent' => 0, 'pricing_value' => '0', 'attribute_id' => '192')
            )
            ,'attribute_id' => 192
            ,'attribute_code' => 'rivers_size'
            ,'frontend_label' => 'Rivers Size'
            ,'html_id' => 'config_super_product__attribute_1')
    );
$mpr->setConfigurableProductsData($productData);
$mpr->setConfigurableAttributesData($attributeData);
$mpr->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
$mpr->save();
```

Comment: I fixed a bug where the following attribute set id was incorrect.
->setAttributeSetId(10) 

Now when I create the configurable product and open it in the backend, I get this message:

Select Configurable Attributes
Only attributes with scope "Global", input type "Dropdown" and Use To Create Configurable Product "Yes" are available.

Material  
Size  
Cotton  
Color  
Colour Group

I selected size and color, and clicked continue, however, there are still no associated products.

Answer (score 2):

Add this code before $mpr->save();

```
$SKU = "any-simple product sku enter here";
$productid = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                  ->getIdBySku(trim($SKU));
$mpr->assignProduct($productid);
```

And set simple product sku in $SKU variable. and i have check that when i select global variable then after i see associated product in configure product.

Its work fine !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting redirected to `select attribute` page, this means that attribute data you set in this sample is not saved correctly.
Try viewing `catalog_product_super_attribute` after script run (new rows should be added).